# Remove Task from Tuleap Sprint menu

Tags: tuleap

I've done *something* that has added *Task* to my project Sprint and Backlog menus.[image: menu screen shot]Also, Tasks appear in the Backlog, along with the User Stories to which they belong (i.e., they appear effectively *twice* in the Backlog).  This is almost certainly down to my playing around with Tuleap in the early days of using it, but now I cannot find what I've done.  I don't think it's tracker hierachy[image] because that is the same as in another project, which doesn't have the same problem.

What have I done?

Answer (score 0):

Agile Dashboard / Administration / Sprint Planning: Edit and change the multiselection against "This planning allows assignment of".